# Running AngularDart with the latest dart SDK (null safety)

Tags: angular-dart

I'm using the latest version of the Dart SDK (2.13.3) and latest version of webdev (2.7.4).

When running "webdev build --null-safety=unsound" I'm getting errors like "Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety".

Then it list a bunch of packages including angular, angular_components, etc..

How do I build/serve an AngularDart web app using the latest version of dart-sdk but still use packages that haven't opted in?

Comment: Not sure you can, how did you manage to get `dart pub get` passing ? dependency_overrides? Last time I checked it was not passing.

Comment: Also you should probably put `--null-safety=unsound` into build.yaml under `dart2js_args`